# Android, How to know which page of ViewPager has been clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

Based on `FragmentPagerAdapter`, I have inflated my view pager and I can see my items in each page. How to know, which page is clicked by user to direct him/her see detail of information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the current displayed `Fragment` by the  `FragmentPagerAdapter`, so what I can suggest is keep an `position` member variable for each `Fragment` that is added in the `pager` so you can use that to know which fragment is clicked.

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu Latcu, what about ViewPager? I didn't find find any interface like the interface that list has(View.OnItemSelected Listener). ViewPager just has OnClickListener which will not be activated when I click on it regardless of which page i am.